# Python thread passing argument difference

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to make simple gui for school purposes and i've met a weird problem:
This case works:

```
   def start_thread(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.th1 = Thread(target=self.createSocket())
        self.th1.start()
    def stopfunc(self):
        self.stop = True
        self.p.kill()
        self.stopbutton['text'] = "Stopped"
        self.th1.join()
```

This one doesn't (Cant change values in thread):

```
   def start_thread(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.th1 = Thread(target=self.createSocket)
        self.th1.start()
    def stopfunc(self):
        self.stop = True
        self.p.kill()
        self.stopbutton['text'] = "Stopped"
        self.root.after(500,self.th1.join)
```

I am wondering whats the difference between calling function with brackets () or without brackets, in this particular case.

Comment: `target=self.createSocket()` will have no effect except `self.createSocket()` returns a function reference because `target` option expects a function reference.

Comment: Use parentheses and the function is called. Don't use parentheses and you just get the address of the function without actually calling it.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks! I've just realized my mistake.